# how to call procedure returning cursor with a date input using cx_Oracle

Tags: python, database, oracle, cx-oracle

I need to query an object using a date where the results are returned as a refcursor, if i just add the date to the function i get returned (date is not itterable). i've tried sending the time just as a string and that doesnt work either, i get a `ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string`

procedure I'm using

```
PROCEDURE prc_get_some_data(
    p_date          IN  DATE,
    p_cursor        OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
    DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO ('Python Script');
    OPEN p_cursor FOR
        SELECT * 
        FROM table
        WHERE creates = p_date;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
        THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);  
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(10));  
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);  
END prc_get_somedatas;
```

python script

```
import sys, time
from datetime import date, timedelta
import random
import cx_Oracle
import string

# Python Script to call a PL/SQL stored procedure to bulk load data


class Test:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.__db = cx_Oracle.connect('/@wallet_string')
        self.__cursor = self.__db.cursor()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.__cursor.close()
        self.__db.close()


    def get_some_data(self):
        d=date.today() # Initialize a date variable with date of today

        db_start = time.time() 
        start_all = time.time()

        self.__cursor.bindarraysize = 2500 
        self.__cursor.arraysize = 10000 

        # create a cursor variable to return the results into
        l_cur = self.__cursor.var(cx_Oracle.CURSOR)

        #execute the procedure
        l_test = self.__cursor.callproc("prc_get_some_data",[datetime.strptime("2007-12-31 23:59:59", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), l_cur])[0]


        db_elapsed = (time.time() - db_start)
        total_elapsed = (time.time() - start_all)

        print "DB:\t ", db_elapsed, " seconds"  
        print "Total:\t ", total_elapsed, " seconds"  

        return list(l_test)



if __name__ == "__main__":

    with Test() as mydbconn:
        for row in mydbconn.get_corporate_actions_equities():
            print row
```

database oracle 12c
client: 12.1.0.2
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out thanks to a colleague
ret_cursor should be the last item in the tuple returned by callproc. So instead of [0], we should have [-1].

```
def get_some_data(self):
    d=date.today() # Initialize a date variable with date of today

    db_start = time.time() 
    start_all = time.time()

    self.__cursor.bindarraysize = 2500 
    self.__cursor.arraysize = 10000 

    # create a cursor variable to return the results into
    l_cur = self.__cursor.var(cx_Oracle.CURSOR)

    #execute the procedure
    rep_date = date(2017,07,20)
    l_test = self.__cursor.callproc("prc_get_some_data",[rep_date, l_cur])[-1]


    db_elapsed = (time.time() - db_start)
    total_elapsed = (time.time() - start_all)

    print "DB:\t ", db_elapsed, " seconds"  
    print "Total:\t ", total_elapsed, " seconds"  

    return list(l_test)
```